# How to extend SAPUI5 TimePickerSlider control's Aggregation Items

Tags: sapui5, aggregation

i am not too familiar with extending SAP standard controls.

Is there a way to extend TimePickerSlider **aggregation *items*** to display **more than 24 hours** on the **hours slider**?

[image]

On the hours slider I need to be able to select any number between 0 - 99. Currently the hour slider is restricted to 23 hours and 24 hours (when support2400 is set to true). I don't need to change anything on the minutes slider. Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the TimePickerSlider for your special case ?.

There are other controls, e.g. a RangeSlider or Slider. Or just write a custom control, [here](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#/topic/d12d2ee6a5454d799358d425f9e7c4db) is an example.

Comment: RangeSlider and Slider wont work because i am working with Time and they are both meant for a horizontal visual range selection. And i am following the Fiori design guidelines

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* need to use TimePickerSliders, you'll have to define a custom control extending sap.m.TimePickerSliders and override `_generatePickerListValues()` there. That should be a rather simple modification, but might still be incompatible with future releases of UI5.

Comment: i have already extended _setupLists() instead because that's were the hours limit to 23 or 24 is set. However, i have managed to solve my question. I will post the answer soon.